# How to convert an Outlook 2007 .ost file to a .pst file, so I can open it in another, local computer?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a couple of backed up .pst and .ost files that were used with a server that is not accessible anymore. On my local machine, I was able to Add... the .pst file to my fresh Outlook 2007 and access the emails. However, adding an .ost file does not seem to be an options in the Accounts Settings dialog.

Is it possible to import the .ost file, or convert it to a .pst w/o the aid of the exchange server?

Comment: you can find many software that will do that for you: http://tinyurl.com/63o7hc2

Comment: Thanks @JMax - I was hoping for a method from within Outlook or Office. Google search found only paid software.

Comment: unfortunately, as .ost and .pst are proprietary formats from MS, I don't know if anything *out-of-the-box* would work. Maybe these software have a trial version?

Comment: The couple of software I found have a *limited* trial version that won't let you go all the way to actually create that .pst.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I faced a similar problem and fixed it with programs like

1. [ostpst](http://www.ostpst.org/)
2. [osttopst](http://osttopstconversion-tool.blogspot.com/)
3. [ost2pst](http://www.fileol.com/utilities/ost2pst-tool-v3.2.html)
4. [Systools](http://www.ostpst.ostconvertertopst.org/)
5. [INTRIGUA](http://www.intrigua.com/convert-ost/)

**Disclaimer**
This is not to advertize, but to give a warning one downloading free software.

As I have downloaded a lot of free stuff that worked for me, I'm not responsible if you download any viruses

Comment: Thanks, @davejal. It has been a while since asking the question, and I don't have access to these files anymore, so I cannot verify your answer. Hopefully someone out there will find it useful. +1 anyway.